# SVG Html code to SVG Image

Tags: jquery, html, svg, inkscape

My new issue consists in the following: i dont know too much about svg and i just downloaded inkscape with the purpose of converting a html+javascript svg code [ i know it sounds odd,but i have a svg map ] to a svg image.

To make it clearer: i have my country's regions map in svg code and i need to make a little modification to add the capital inside a region.

How can i do this?

Here's [the map](http://ctrl-d.ro/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/index.html)that i've used.

PS: i mention that the link i've posted has nothing to do with me.

Comment: Design comment: you should allocate more space for the right panel. Not even the horizontal scrollbar fits on the screen on 1024x? screens.

Comment: Please post some code here. If your site goes dead or changes, this question won't be useful to anyone.

Comment: What type of modifications? Do you need to change color, shape, etc?  Do you need this to occur on a specific event? More details please.

Comment: AFAIUC, the same effect (animate the color on hover) can be achieved without javascript. The browsers that understand inline SVG also understand CSS3 transitions, and inline SVG can be styled via external CSS.

Comment: No,i need to draw another small area inside a region thats already mapped. So i need to add a little shape inside one that's already on the map.
@JanDvorak it isnt my site and it looks kind of stable. i do not have a better link and i copied the map from that website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just open up Web Inspector in Chrome (or Firebug in Firefox) and select the SVG, copy it, paste it into a text editor and save with the SVG extension (e.g. map.svg). Then open it in Inkscape.[image]

Comment: Finally a man who understood what i want! I tried doing this,but inkscape gives me the following error when i try to open the edited file :  `Failed to load the requested file`.  Does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have Inkscape but it opens perfectly in Illustrator. Make sure you are copying all the SVG, I've put the source here: http://jsfiddle.net/RzEJq/ you can copy and paste it into a new file.

Comment: Wont you be sweeter than you look in the profile picture and draw a shape for me?

Comment: come on mate,dont lose this opportunity. is just a small service and you'll get some extra point for doing it. you'll earn more respect and popularity on the web and you can make jokes from a higher level then. You'll earn another badge,like heroes do. Dont hesitate to be a hero.

Comment: I already have all the worthless internet points that I'll need in my lifetime, but just for the sake of the absurdity of this situation I'll help you. What do you need?

Comment: I need you to think more often to the people that are less smarter,capable and wealthier than you and act like a hero if you want to feel something worthy. While doing all things said before,you can blend good deeds with praying. Lowering your ears to my words wouldnt be what i need,but what i want most.
I,for one,think i can handle this thing by myself with a little reading. Thanks anyway.